# How can I clear all out everything I don't need in the NLA editor?

Tags: animation, unity, nla-editor

In my project, NLA editor is filled up with all of the objects in the scene and when I import this to unity, animations mess up (imported asset has all animations of all objects even thow there is only one animation in one object). How can I clear all out everything I don't need in the NLA editor?
[image: part of NLA editor]

Usually NLA editor has only the object I am animating, this time everything is included. And when imported to unity all of the animations merge into DefaultTake instead of being separate (there should be only one animation and it should be separate of default take);

Comment: Try using Edit > Remove Empty Animation Data

Comment: That kinda worked, still, there is only the DefaultTake when I import the model to Unity. Shoot and DefaultTake are not separated, instead DefaultTake is Shoot now. I can live with that.